# <a> anchors / fragment identifiers don't seem to work

Tags: html, anchor

I have markup like this on somepage.html:

```
<div class='someclass' id='hashtag1'>
  <h1>somecontent</h1>
</div>
<div class='someclass' id='hashtag2'>
  <h1>somecontent</h1>
</div>
<div class='someclass' id='hashtag3'>
  <h1>somecontent</h1>
</div>
```

And links like this on another page (let's call it someotherpage.html):

```
<a href='somepage.html#hashtag1'>first content div</a>
<a href='somepage.html#hashtag2'>second content div</a>
<a href='somepage.html#hashtag3'>third content div</a>
```

However when I click on one of these links I don't see the expected behaviour - the page loads as normal but the scrollTop of the window doesn't match these divs. I've tried changing the IDs as they had hyphens in the to start with, this didn't make any difference - I've also tried changing what element the ID is on, i.e changed the `<h1>` to have the ID, then changed the `<h1>` to an anchor, but no luck.

When I'm already on the page, if I edit the hasthag and hit enter, it works as expected - changing the scrolltop of the window to the element with the ID of the hashtag without refreshing the page - but it doesn't work on the first hit.

Am I missing something obvious here?

EDIT:

- Using FF 9.0.1 on Mac OSX
- Turned JS off using web developer toolbar
- changing or removing CSS doesn't seem to make any difference

UPDATE:
This works fine if I enable javascript - which is exactly when it doesn't need to work.
I have this as a catch for users with no javascript / disabled js. WTF, firefox?

Comment: I'm assuming `#hashtag1` on the second and third content link is a typo?

Comment: @Curt yeah, well spotted - i'll update the question

Comment: hashtags are a Twitter thing, those are [fragment identifiers (in URIs)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and [anchors (in HTML documents)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3)

Comment: I *AM* missing something obvious then :) thanks, will update question

Comment: I'd *guess* that you might have reflowing content (e.g. images without a height and width specified that would let the browser create placeholder space) which is mucking up the browser's scroll algorithm. A test case would be useful.

Comment: Which browser? Seems ok to me and works in FF3.0.4 (don't ask).

Comment: @Quentin the divs have a width set and are inside a fixed width container but no heights are set. I'll try unstyling the divs and see if it changes things. Don't think I would be able to make a test case in jsfiddle though as the page gets requested.

Comment: css doesn't seem to affect this. I should also mention that this happens with JS switched off - i'll update the question incase this has any bearing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your specific example, it seems to me that the scrollTop only changes when the page is already long enough to require scrolling.

When all the content is in view, the scrollTop position remains at the top of the document however when the page requires some scrolling, the scrollTop scrolls as far as the document can already scroll.

If scrolling to the required ID does not exceed the total possible scroll position, then the element in question will apear at the top of the page, otherwise the document will only scroll to it's maximum (based on its content).

Comment: +1 for insightful / lateral thinking answer - however on the page where I'm getting this, the content is plenty long enough to scroll. Also if I edit the anchor after loading the page, it scrolls as I would expect - it's just when requesting the page that this issue crops up.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to see the page(s) in question?

Comment: sorry, it's part of a site I'm working on for a client. I realise that makes it difficult but I don't feel comfortable making it live at the moment

Answer (score -5):

Hashtags don't work with `id`s. You have to put `a` tags like this: `<a name="foo"></a>`. Then you can link to them using `<a href="#foo">go to foo</a>`. Same goes for linking between multiple pages.

Comment: You have to go back to Netscape 4 to find a browser that doesn't support [this part of the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3).